# Как удалить workspace в intelij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

У меня была ветка с определенными настройками (workspace)

при ее мереж в current возникают конфликты т.к. гит пытается эти же настройки запихнуть в каррент.

но я не понимаю как этот workspace удалить.

Comment: немного не понял суть проблемы, а в `.gitignore`, папка `.idea` добавлена?

Comment: ну то есть, в определенной ветке вы прям ввели историю правок в `workspace`, или просто работая в какой-то ветке, вы просто поправили настройки и теперь они тянутся

Comment: да, работая в какой-то ветке, поправил настройки

Comment: а все решил) помог $ git fetch --prune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте `.gitignore` и если там нет записи, добавьте

```
.idea/
```

так же удалите папку из гита

```
git rm -r --cached .idea
```